# How is this array outside the bounds?

Tags: c#, arrays, command-line

I don't understand why this is outside the bounds of the array? This array is supposed to accept these command line arguments but every time I compile I have been thrown this exception. I am new to programming so this could be obvious.

**Code:**

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] CommandLine = new string [4];

    string configFile = args[0];
    string file1 = args[1];
    string file2 = args[2];

    Console.WriteLine("configfile is " + configFile);
    Console.WriteLine("file1 is " + file1);
    Console.WriteLine("file2 is " + file2);
    Console.Read();
}
```

**Error:**
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`string[] args` is a special parameter here, this is an array of command line arguments passed to the application during start-up. If there are no arguments passed in - you will get exactly this exception. Or as in your case, no argument within `args` with that index.

You can inspect your `args` during debugging and see what are the actual values of it.